# Assigning output of a Dynamic Performance View (v$asm_diskgroup) to a variable in Shell Script

Tags: shell, shell-script, oracle-database, oracle-linux

I am trying to assign the output of

> select name from v$asm_diskgroup;

to a variable in Shell . The script is failing because of special character '$' in the table name  .

Note : While i tried assigning value of " select sysdate from dual" it worked like charm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Query that worked:

```
count=$(sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
        select sysdate from dual;
        exit;
END
)
echo $count
```

Query in which I am facing issue:

```
count=$(sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
        select name from v$asm_diskgroup
        exit;
END
)
echo $count
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your string with a $ in single quotes:

```
value=$(... 'select name from v$asm_diskgroup;')
```

Otherwise, the shell will try to expand a variable named asm_diskgroup.  The shell will not expand variables within single quotes.

Comment: Facing the error . `SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "'select na..." - rest of line ignored.`

Comment: Can you paste what you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an simple work around for this:

Instead of using

> v$asm_diskgroup

I have assigned it to an variable

```
tab='v$asm_diskgroup'

count=$(sqlplus -s $configuser/$configpass@$ORACLE_SID <<END
    select name from $tab;
    exit;
END 
)
echo $count
```